# Ubuntu 19.04 Freeze at loading DELL E6430 i5 - nomodeset didn't work well

Tags: dual-boot, dell, 19.04

I've got problem with new Ubuntu 19.04. I installed plain version along with windows 10. First login was ok, but after when I logged in to windows 10, and tried back to Ubuntu again - It got stuck on loading Ubuntu (screen with 5 dots). When I tried to change "quiet splash" for "nomodeset", I've received an error "hdaudio hdaudioC0D3: Unable to bind codec"

After that I've tried to reinstall Ubuntu, but nothing changed

My Computer:
DELL E6430
Intel i5

Answer (score 6):

I found solution:

When GRUB is open click E and change from "quiet splash" to nothing, just delete. After that Ubuntu will open.

1. Open terminal and write 
   "sudo nano /etc/deafult/grub"
2. on line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" delete "quiet splash". After that it looks like this GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
3. save this and write in terminal: "sudo update-grub"
4. Restart and after that it's ok. You can use windows and Ubuntu as well. You'll do't see any errors.

Comment: Worked! I also had `nomodeset` and removed that as well. Mine was a Lenovo with Intel Graphics.