# Can't boot Ubuntu 18.04 from USB

Tags: boot, grub2, sound

I created a Linux Live USB key with Ubuntu 18.04 and turned off Secure Boot on my Surface Laptop 3, but whatever I try it just fails to boot! :-(

**Regular boot (has "quiet splash" option)**

-> `MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list`

**Boot in compatability mode (has "nosplash" option)**

-> `hdaudioC0D2: Unable to bind the codec`

No success with other versions of Ubuntu and Linux Mint I tried either. I tried modifying the boot options manually but I'm not sure how to turn off or choose a different audio driver/codec.

---

**Regular boot after removing "quiet splash" option**

Laptop starts getting loud and overheating after the line

`[  OK  ] Started udev Kernel Device Manager.`

**Regular boot after replacing "quiet splash" option with "text"**

Either the same as above happens or I get this output:

```
A start job is running for Set the console keyboard layout (13s / no limit)
Kernel panic - not syncing: Timeout: Not all CPUs entered broadcast exception handler
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148387/modsign-couldnt-get-uefi-db-list-couldnt-get-size-0x800000000000000e) and [Ubuntu 19.04 Freeze at loading DELL E6430 i5 - nomodeset didn't work well](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144224/ubuntu-19-04-freeze-at-loading-dell-e6430-i5-nomodeset-didnt-work-well)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 19.04 Freeze at loading DELL E6430 i5 - nomodeset didn't work well](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144224/ubuntu-19-04-freeze-at-loading-dell-e6430-i5-nomodeset-didnt-work-well)

Comment: @Melebius The "noapic noacpi nosplash" thing DOES make it boot (which is weird cos compatability mode includes the same options) but it's completely unresponsive both to built-in mouse+keyboard+touchscreen and USB-connected mouse+keyboard =/

Comment: @Melebius I'll try tomorrow with a USB hub (for connecting mouse, ethernet and live usb), I think that might work!

Comment: So I had one successful boot but I either keep not getting into the GUI or, if I do, Cinnamon keeps crashing so I just endlessly restart it

Answer (score 1):

What ended up working for me was

1. When booting, edit the command line (press `e`) to add `noapic` to boot options
2. Use Ubuntu Mate instead of Linux Mint because Cinnamon kept crashing
3. Install kernel `debian-test-2` from [here](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/) so keyboard touchpad etc. work